# replace the "+=" operator in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following inside a while loop.

```
rptGhrecords.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + rptGhrecordsListItem1.get_id() + "</td>"
```

but i would rather use JQuery,  how do i replicate the "+=" from the above in jquery below?

```
$(rptGhrecords).html("<tr><td>" + rptGhrecordsListItem1.get_id() + "</td>" +
```

Comment: `.append()`? try `$(rptGhrecords).append("<tr><td>" + rptGhrecordsListItem1.get_id() + "</td>")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need .append

http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$("rptGhrecords").append("<tr><td>" + rptGhrecordsListItem1.get_id() + "</td>");
```

Answer (score 2):

To replicate the `+=` with `innerHTML`, you'd use `html()` with a callback :

```
$(rptGhrecords).html(function(i, html) {
    return html + "<tr><td>" + rptGhrecordsListItem1.get_id() + "</td>";
});
```

Using `append()` would do the same thing

```
$(rptGhrecords).append("<tr><td>" + rptGhrecordsListItem1.get_id() + "</td>")
```

Note that adding partial markup, such as an opening `<tr>` without a closing `</tr>` is generally not a very good idea.